# Why is she looking at her hands in the end in movie Morgan?

Tags: plot-device, morgan

In the last scene of [Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_(2016_film)) we see Lee looking at her hands. During her evaluation, Morgan also looked at her hands (palms up, palms down) in same way.

**Is there connection between Lee and Morgan? Why are they doing the same action?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original script is a little more telling. It would appear that in much the same way that different divisions of Omni Consumer Products developed [multiple *robotics* programs](https://youtu.be/GLQiskRb02o?t=27s), Omnicron Corporation has allowed multiple divisions of the company (including SynSect) to develop their own genetic assassins, with some projects dramatically more advanced than others.

The staff are somewhat suprised to learn of a second facility;

> **LEE** (CONT'D): *Clean up crew from corporate will be here at daybreak to collect the specimen and transport it for a full autopsy
>   at an alternate facility.*
>
> **ZIEGLER:** *Alternate facility? Absurd. Absolutely absurd. Even if - if - I were to consent to the manual termination, there's no one else
>   able to process the minutiae of the work involved. The work must be
>   done here.*

and we receive proof positive of a second program

> **JIM BRYCE** (V.O.): *But I think these events make it punishingly clear what I had already suggested....*
>
> INT. CORPORATE TRUCK - DAY Morgan's corpse is settled into its casing,
>   the lid closed.
>
> **JIM BRYCE** (V.O.): *The L9* [Lee] *was the inferior program.*

A common feature (and presumably one that "Corporate" has insisted on) is that the hybrids are mentally conditioned to periodically perform a particular gesture, thus allowing those in the know to tell the difference between a human and a hybrid.

**The hand gesture is the film's way of offering a twist. In the final scene we realise that Lee isn't just another "suit from corporate". She is, in fact, the product of their secondary lab, sent to Synsect's 'Grant Farms' laboratory with the explicit instructions to not only *assess* the risk that Morgan poses but also to terminate her should the scientists prove unwilling or incapable.**

Comment: oh ok .. thanks @valorum. Because Morgan had extra-sensory it is not possible that she takes over Lee's mind?

Comment: @Gomes - The whole ESP/telekinesis shtick seems to have been tacked on after the original screenplay was written. It's *possible* that she was taken over but there's absolutely no foreshadowing that such a thing can be done (for example, we don't see Morgan taking control of anything else) and the idea definitely conflicts with the original ending.

Comment: I would argue that Lee/L4 is the primary program and L9/Morgan the secondary given that Lee is obviously older and 4 < 9. I have another question though, but wondered if you could share your source for the script?

Comment: @IanNewson - Unfortunately the script is behind a paywall to which I no longer have access

Answer (score 0):

This scene is a visual cue to the audience that confirms the plot twist that

> Lee is also a hybrid, the same as Morgan but an earlier model, hence the similar hand gesture.